# How to verify the publisher of a message to a service bus using VSTS server-based task?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-extensions

I want to use [Publish To Azure Service Bus VSTS server task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-to-azure-service-bus?view=vsts) and verify on the recipient side the VSTS **user**, **project** and **account** from which the published message originated. According to [task.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/557ad987038a972695c48394997f3fc18ec2a198/Tasks/PublishToAzureServiceBusV1/task.json#L96-L113) related information is being posted onto the service bus, but for my purposes this is not secure, as I want to protect myself against client spoofing the information. Multiple different VSTS users, projects and accounts will be using the task. Once a client of the task has credentials to post to the service bus, she can spoof the data.

Does VSTS provide a tamper-proof identity provisioning of the message publisher? The message has [auth token](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/557ad987038a972695c48394997f3fc18ec2a198/Tasks/PublishToAzureServiceBusV1/task.json#L112), but it appears to serve different purpose: it is used to authenticate to VSTS and has no identity claims in it.

Comment: No, there isn't. What's the data that you can used to verify?

Comment: The requirement is that members of multiple projects within Microsoft post to the same service bus, and our service, reading from the service bus, has to guarantee that a a member of one project cannot post on behalf of a different project. We would like to have at least VSTS-project-level granularity, possibly even user-level. In the linked `task.json` that would be the `ProjectId` key.

The workaround solution we are considering is to write a VSTS extension that modifies the built-in task by adding an additional shared secret, which our service will check against to prevent spoofing.

Comment: We have recently added an option to sign the message payload in the azure service bus task. Will that work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Aseem Bansal, `The Publish To Azure Service Bus` VSTS server task has a new feature: `Signing properties`. One can provide a `Certificate Variable` which is a shared secret between the sender (VSTS extension) and recipent (the service consuming messages from the Service Bus). Value of such variable should be kept as [secret variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#secret-variables). This solves the issue, as any spoofing attempts can be blocked by checking against the presence of shared secret in the Service Bus message (the recipient has to keep a mapping which senders should know which secrets). The scope of who knows the secret can be controlled by who can view the VSTS build/release definition secret variables and submit builds/releases from given definition. I believe VSTS has fairly fine-grained control over it, to the level of specific users.

Answer (score 0):

You can include necessary information in Message body, otherwise, you need to custom release task.

```
{"requestUserId":"$(Release.RequestedForId)","requestUser":"$(Release.RequestedFor)"}
```

Comment: That's correct, but I am afraid somebody can impersonate the user ID, by sending forged message. I was hoping VSTS provides such information in a tamper-proof manner, e.g. encoded as a Claim in the OAuth token. However, this is not the case.

Comment: There isn't such feature in Azure Service Bus task, you may custom task through VSTS extension.

Comment: Starian, I think there is such feature. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51035492/986533)